# Inflate view in Android - View not keeping Padding EVEN when Parent is specified

Tags: android, view, parent, inflate, layoutparams

I'm working on an app that is basically done but I'm reviewing the code to optimize. I found a Guide to inflating which states that its well to use the "parent" part of the inflate so that you can keep the layoutparams - which I in my original version did not do - instead I set these programmatically.

Now onward to the problem. I've changed my code (look below) to incorporate the View but the layoutparameters are not added, and I still have to add them programmatically.

The original code, this *works* however I'm not happy with having to set the layoutparams
(observe that I've shorten the code a bit to make it easier to read, I have not removed anything of interest):

```
    // this is the parent
    LinearLayout llCategory = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llCategory);

    categoryArrayList = db.getCategory();  // this gets the data for me.


    // Add the Categories 
    for (int i = 0; i < categoryArrayList.size(); i++) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // This is my original inflate
        //View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_standard, null);
        // this is the inflate I would like to use.
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_standard, llCategory, false);


        LinearLayout llCard = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llStandardCard);

        // here is some code where I change the background of llCard - which is the base layout for the view I inflated above.


        // this is where I have to set the paddings programmatically on the view (or rather the linear layout that the view contains)

        // get the right paddings for the card and set them.
        int standardPadding = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.standard_padding);
        int bottomPadding = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.standard_card_padding_bottom);

        llCard.setPadding(standardPadding, standardPadding,standardPadding,bottomPadding);


        // Add the complete view to the layout.
        llCategory.addView(view);
}
```

So to recap. Regardless whether I use this version of inflate:
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_standard, null);

or if I use this version of inflate:
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_standard, llCategory, false);

I have to set the padding (which is already set in the XML) programmatically - what am I doing wrong.

Edit, adding XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llStandardCard"
        style="@style/StandardCardStyle">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStandardRowText"
            style="@style/RowText"/>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also the style:

```
<style name="StandardCardStyle" parent="@style/AbstractCard">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/standard_half_padding</item>

    <!--Very custom paddings due to the background messing with the standard ones-->
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/standard_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/standard_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/standard_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/standard_card_padding_bottom</item>


    <item name="android:layout_gravity">top</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: post layout file row_standard.xml

Comment: Looking at my standard_card.xml i see that i have the llCard Linear layout nested inside another linear layout. If i remember correctly i did this due to problems with paddings etc in the first place. could this be whats back to haunt me?
See above for the XML

Comment: where do you set the paddings in xml? I can't see it...

Comment: Sorry, added the correct style wich contains the paddings.
Also, removing the outer LinearLayout did nothing except mess with the margins between the cards

Comment: and where are you setting the background? is it a nine patch drawable?

Comment: Pskink i set the background, which is a xml selector that points to several 9 patches at the comment: // here is some code where i change the background of llCard - wich is the bace layout for the view i inflated above.

Comment: paddings are not part of layoutparameters they are part of the view itself, however they can be messed with paddings from nine patches so a basic idea is to not use paddings at all in your nine patches and see how it goes or post a screenshot of them to investigate...

Comment: i'm facing similar issue do you have any success?

Comment: The answer was as Christos suggested that the 9patch had its own paddigs. See his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

LayoutParams as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) are part of a groupview. They are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out. They have nothing to do with paddings. Padding is part of the view itself. Your problem is that you cannot preserve the paddings of your llCard which are defined in the xml files.

My best guess based on the info of your question (and comments) is that you are using paddings both in the xml layout file and in the selectors and or in the 9 patches. I think that padding defined in the 9 patches takes higher priority because they are applied during the drawing of the view and thus the paddings from xml layout are ignored.

So my suggestion is to either use your paddings ONLY in the 9 patches or ONLY in the xml layout NOT in both.

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) about the 9 patches padding area.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hm, this sounds reasonable, I'm away from my Dev machine but will try out to edit out the padding of the 9patxhes when I get home in a few days. To keep the load of the app down i only have one set of 9patches for all  sizes so editing the padding there seems out of the question. Thank you!